# 20.04 to 22.04 Upgrade Failure

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade my Ubuntu and I get this:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,268 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease              
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]   
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]    
Fetched 336 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
None

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Please, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `-d`(*which is to go to the development release*), [Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/) has been released and `-d` is not required

Comment: Either way, same result.

Comment: Try disable the "nordvpn" repo before upgrade.